# How to build a java project using the command line?

Tags: java, project

I am a student and I **hate** not knowing how things are organized. I'd like to be able to create a full on java project from scratch on the command line. I'd like to be able to import jars and set the classpath, make packages and import them. ALso learn about environment variables. I currently do not know much about organizing code. I just know how to code in Java.

Is there a textbook, online article or the like that allows one to learn how to organize a java project?

I do not want any involvement with eclipse or any IDE. I am willing to learn Maven, XML, or the likes to accomplish my goal.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'organize.' There are lots of ways Java projects are organized, some of which depend on the framework you're using, or the purpose of the application, or the external systems with which you have to integrate; etc. Can you be a bit clearer about what your java project is for?

Comment: @BillHorvath I mean on how to setup the classpath and make a jar file and a package. At my school, they usually just have us download a jar file and eclipse sets up everything. I just wanna know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a student willing to have a Java programming career, it might help to learn how to do things from command line, e.g. edit the files, compiling the classes, testing and building the project. Oracle tutorials provide example on this matter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2

However, I strongly advise you to embrace an IDE as your Java career will mostly reside in an IDE as real life projects are BIG! There are tons of helpful things the IDE does to you out of the box or to simplify things. Since you are a student, I will give you one basic example besides compiling: a class with 10 fields requires you some typing for getters, setters, hashCode, equals. Alternative? Few keystrokes to instruct the IDE to generate them for you. And that's one basic example.

Regarding the project structure, embracing the (since you mentioned it) Maven project structure of `src/main/{java,resources}, src/test/{java,resources}` even if you do NOT use Maven. This will let you forget about organizing the files around.

If you were asking about structuring the classes in the right packages, you will figure out yourself as you gain experience. Rule of thumb is to group classes together by functionality they provide. Additionally, if the packages are organized right, if you change something and touching a few classes, ideally you'd want the changed classes to be located in a single package if possible.

Learning Maven is a good choice as it is a powerful tool for building a project and keeping things organized (project structure, project dependencies, etc.).

Comment: I think I will try my hand at Maven and just stick with eclipse. I've encountered numerous errors with maven when I do dumb things in eclipse out of ignorance on how package management works.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Java program can be compiled trivially by `javac MyMainClass.java`, provided that your `CLASSPATH` list directories and jars with its dependencies.

Compiling a large Java project is *not* trivial. There are several tools intended to make it simpler.

- [Gradle](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/): very widely used, uses its own language, very powerful and complex.
- [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven): Still widely used. Uses XML to describe everything.
- Apache [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) is lower level and lower abstraction power.

The power of these tools lies exactly in hiding the boilerplate of the Java project building process. They generate a skeleton of a build for you, and provide higher-level operations.

Of course you can start with simplest and watch the steps these tools make.

Reading the docs for `javac` and `jar` thoroughly does help, too.